# What's apt-get's equivalent option of this dpkg command?

Tags: apt, dpkg

```
dpkg -L <package>
```

This command gives me a list of all the installed files, what's apt-get's equivalent option for it? I read the man page but couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like Dennis said, `apt-get` is a layer on top of `dpkg` (or other local package managers such as `rpm`). `dpkg` manages the local packages on the machine, while `apt-get` provides a way to grab packages from distant repositories and resolve dependencies between packages that will be handed to `dpkg`.

```
dpkg -L <package_file>
```

lists the files provided by a package already installed on the machine.

With apt-get, you might want to list the files that a package provides, even if it is not installed in your system. Fortunately for you, there is a tool for that, called `apt-file`, which needs to be installed in addition to `apt-get`. You can use it this way:

```
# Install apt-file
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
# update apt-file's cache (different than apt-get's, namely apt-cache)
$ sudo apt-file update
# display the contents of a package
$ sudo apt-file list <package_name>
```

Note that `apt-file` uses special files on the package repository called Contents files. While all official repositories have these files, some third-party repositories might not have them, so `apt-file` won't be able to list the contents of packages on these repositories.

```
man apt-file
```

will also list other nice things you can do with `apt-file`, such as `apt-file search <keyword>` which lets you find which packages provide a given file.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent. `apt-get` is a layer on top of `dpkg`, not a replacement of it.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache` can be used for some stuff you might want to do:

**Actually listing all packages:**
To actually list all packages that is in `apt-get`'s cache, use `apt-cache pkgnames`. This is very much the equivalent of `dpkg -l` for `apt-get`, except it *only* shows package names, and not any other information that `dpkg` might show.

**NOTE:** Using `apt-cache pkgnames` will generate incredibly much output, on my system it is as much as 39553 lines. To see in advance how many lines it would be on your system, try using `apt-cache stats` (see below).

**Searching:**
Use `apt-cache search <regex> [<regex> [...]]` where `<regex>` is one or more regular expressions to search for.

**Counting:**
Use `apt-cache stats` to show some statistics about that cache since last `apt-get update`.
For instance, an example output might be:

```
Total package names: 39553 (1,582k)
  Normal packages: 30033
  Pure virtual packages: 511
  Single virtual packages: 2762
  Mixed virtual packages: 305
  Missing: 5942
Total distinct versions: 32378 (1,813k)
Total distinct descriptions: 32378 (777k)
Total dependencies: 210651 (5,898k)
Total ver/file relations: 34931 (559k)
Total Desc/File relations: 32378 (518k)
Total Provides mappings: 5816 (116k)
Total globbed strings: 169 (2,278)
Total dependency version space: 1,052k
Total slack space: 73.4k
Total space accounted for: 10.0M
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't exist. You can use the GUI synaptic which will show you all the installed packages.

Shown below.

[image]